# Realtime API Java suport and examples

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm trying to use realtime api in java. I have found many examples in javascript but none in java. Is java supported and if not how i'm i going to implement my java app using the functionality of real time api?
I have searched allover the drive api java version and found nothing about the realtime api.
Please any help is really appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Realtime API is currently only available in javascript.

Comment: thank you for your answer. is there any way use it in my swing and android app?